# Hard drive working in 5 second pulses?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, performance

Bit of an odd issue with a laptop (Toshiba C660D 181).

For most of the time, the hard drive seems to operating in 5 second pulses. The laptop doesn't have a HDD light and the HDD itself is very quiet, but the resource monitor seems to demonstrate this;

[image: Resource Monitor, 5 second pulses]

As does this DiskMon log

http://pastebin.com/RGC7JJjH

In this state the laptop is incredibly slow - Firefox can take 10+ minutes to load up, half a minute to display text entered on the keyboard, endless "Not responding" window states etc.

Occasionally without any user trigger, the computer will operate as normal, which seems to be reflected in the resource monitor again;

[image: Resource Monitor, all normal?]

However it will go back to operating in 5 second pulses, again without anything obvious triggering it.

This was happening before and after a fresh installation of Windows 7.

Comment: I suspect you'll need to replace the drive

Comment: Is the BIOS configured to use the hard disk in compatibility (IDE) mode or AHCI? This may help. Second, have you updated the chipset drivers?

Comment: That is an option (HDD replacement), I'll probably try that the next time I have a look at the laptop.

Comment: Funny you should mention the compatibility/IDE mode - the BIOS has an option to select compatibility (IDE) or SATA mode IIRC. The only way I could get the new Windows 7 install to boot was switching to the compatibility mode. However, the laptop was both booting fine and showing the above symptoms with the previous W7 install in the SATA mode (or AHCI mode, don't have the laptop with me at the moment). I'm sure all drivers were installed before, but I'll check all drivers are installed from Toshiba on the new W7 install before trying the different HDD option.

Comment: Whether it can boot with either mode depends on when it was installed. If you installed it with IDE mode enabled, it won't boot if you change it afterwards. Vice versa too, I think.

Comment: Watching the Resource Monitor can you filter the results to show what is using the disk at the 5s intervals you're experiencing?

Comment: Update - put a different hard drive in and Windows 7 can now be installed with the AHCI option enabled, plus haven't experienced of the previous hard drive behaviour/performance. Looks like the original hard drive is failing, recovering the user data/documents etc. using another machine and had to use TestDisk to restore the partitions half way through. Luckily was able to recover the rest of the data afterwards. @brianbaligad do you want to provide an answer (drive replacement) so I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace the drive. You've described sub-optimal behavior from your disk. It could be the disk is unable to keep up with it's internal error correction due to too many bad sectors.  There may even be something wrong with the internally like misaligned platters (the consistently timed hangs make me wonder about this).

Alternatively, you could use commercial drive maintenance software such as [Spinrite](https://www.grc.com/sr/spinrite.htm) to fix the disk. Spinrite spends hours reading all damaged sectors on the disk and safely rewriting the data back to healthier sectors.  This could help you recover data on the disk if you didn't have a backup.